# Handle Unsupported Media Types in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, http-headers, mime-types

I'm currently building a simple REST service using Spring framework. But when testing using Postman, I have encountered the following issue:
[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYfct.png)

I wonder how to make Spring recognize the received Content-Type header actually match the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is supported.

UPDATED:

I'm current run my app at `localhost` with embedded Tomcat server.

My endpoint briefly includes:

1. POST: `/api/users` - for creating new user
2. GET: `/api/users` - for listing users
3. GET: `/api/users/{id}` - for retrieving user by his id

The request body for POST endpoint:

```
"email":"<your-email>",
"password:"<your-password>"
```

UPDATED 2:

[My Endpoint image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjZw9.png)

Comment: Please update your question with your rest end point

Comment: Don't add images, add your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api/users",consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody User user)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Unsupported Media Type exception is still thrown.